# Raid recovery in gigabyte GA-8I945 Pro

Tags: bios, raid, raid-1, hard-drive-recovery

This was a working machine until a few days ago. Now it won't boot into the OS, during startup it makes clicking sounds (I think from one of the drives).

Installed OS: Windows 2003 Web edition
Hardware: Gigabyte GA-8I945P Pro , 2*160G Sata in RAID1 configuration , 2 Volumes – 25G and the rest.

When I installed windows on it, during setup, I pressed <kbd>F6</kbd> and used ICH7DH drivers of RAID.

The manual for the motherboard says:

Step 1:
After the POST memory test begins and before the operating system boot begins, look for a message which says "Press  to enter Configuration utility" (Figure 4). Press CTRL + I to enter the RAID BIOS setup utility.

But the machine never shows this message.

BIOS SATA RAID/AHCI Mode is set to RAID.

Any ideas or pointers on what I can do to recover my data?

Comment: How about if you disconnect one of the drives - does the clicking stop?  Try it with one then the other to confirm it is one of the drives (it sounds like it).  If so, then you will need to replace that drive before you can get the RAID working again (as a RAID anyway - a single drive should work alone).

Comment: Hi Matt, It was the first thing I tried but oddly both disks seem to make clicking noises (although one more the the other). could it be that they both died together (having been bought togeter) ? Anyway it does not seem as if the machine recognizes any of them alone either.

Comment: Strange for them both to die at the same time in the same way.  That is, if they have died.  I have seen apparant disk problems appearing from a faulty power supply before now.  You might like to try either a new PSU (or borrow one), or try the disks connected to a different computer (or in an external HDD housing).

Comment: Do I need to disable bios Raid for it to work with only one of the disks ?

Comment: I don't know, that depends on how your BIOS RAID works.  Some put special data in certain parts of the drive to identify such things as disk packs and device numbers, so it may not work as a standalone disk.  A single disk in a RAID1 with RAID enabled should work perfectly fine however.

Comment: Is there a way to boot some OS or tool from a CD and have it check the situation ?

Comment: Could also be that the disks died one by one and I did not notice because after the death of the first one things continued to work...

Comment: I usually advocate using Hiren's Boot CD for this: http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/  It contains many diagnostic and testing tools.  Burn it to disc, then boot off that disc, and have a play.